# maven archiva clean up old versions of certain artifacts

Tags: maven, archiva

I was wondering if there was a way of automaticaly cleaning up old versions of certain artifacts.
The specific artifacts that I'm considering are:

- web applications
- executable jars

There should not realy be more than the most recent version used(or a couple versions back) for these artifacts.
The increasingly large amount of versions is filling up diskspace for no reason.

Is there a way to have the most recent 2 or 3 versions for every major release number (for example the 2.x.y for highest values of x and y)?

This is about actual released versions (not just snapshots(these are already automaticaly purged)) and does will not be applied for libraries used by other projects.

If possible, how can it be done?
Do I need an extra tool for this?
Or do i need to write a batch job myself for this?

archiva version:

```
Apache Archiva 1.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently no. Usually maven artifacts are not deleted to ensure build reproducibility.
But you ask a new feature here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM

Comment: Could it be done by creating a custom consumer? i found this link: http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.3.6/customising/writing-consumer.html.

Comment: yes correct you can probably do your own consumer. But have a look at docs for 1.4 (coming 2.0) some java naming has changed.